# How do you enable database logging in production mode? (Rails v2.3.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I have some oddities on my production server only and I need to be able to see all the database queries as in development mode.

I am sure it is a small config tweak, but I can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 2.x, in the environment.rb file you have:

```
  # Force all environments to use the same logger level
  # (by default production uses :info, the others :debug)
  # config.log_level = :debug
```

In Rails 3.x should be something similar.

Comment: Does that work for database logging or just 'logger.debug "some debug message"'?  That was the first thing I tried and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also, check that config/environments/production.rb doesn't have any settings that might be overwriting what you have in environment.rb

Comment: The server was restarted on deployment of the changes, and there is nothing else in the production.rb file related to logging.

Comment: My apologies.  It seems that deploying a new version was not sufficient to reset the settings.  After I pushed out some other changes and noticed no differences I did a restart and the config setting now work.