# DB logging in Rails test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I saw [How do you enable database logging in production mode? (Rails v2.3.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395462/how-do-you-enable-database-logging-in-production-mode-rails-v2-3-8).

Is there a way to enable DB logs in test environment?

I put in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

But I had no luck.

## Edit

I am on Rails 4.

Comment: In the question you referenced, it says the test environment should already use `:debug` by default, and in my `test.log` file, I see lots of sql queries. Have you changed anything in your `application.rb` or `test.rb`?

Comment: nope, my test.rb file has not any line containing log_level.

Answer (score 1):

So, you should follow this steps to get mongoid logs working: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#logging

Basically, you need to include this in your application.rb file:

```
Mongoid.logger.level = Moped.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

Comment: I did that in `config/environments/test.rb` but I had no luck, my development log actually shows mongo output, but my test log does not.